# Passing Array Index numbers from PHP to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, dynamic-arrays

new to JS and PHP and modifying a slideshow script to dynamically display contents of three different directories.  Pretty much keeping things simple to start off with.

One problem I have is that the script I am modifying used the following static code to fill the javascript array:

```
variableslide[0]=['team_a/blank.jpg']
variableslide[1]=['team_a/ford.jpg']
variableslide[2]=['team_a/futuristic.jpg']
variableslide[3]=['team_a/lambo.jpg']
```

My PHP code is working so far to enumerate the directories dynamically and then pass the result on to Javascript:

```
<?php

// Header("content-type: application/x-javascript"); 

$team_a = array();
$team_b = array();
$team_c = array();
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('team_a') as $fileInfo) {
if($fileInfo->isDot() || !$fileInfo->isFile()) continue;
$team_a[] = "team_a".'/'.$fileInfo->getFilename();
}

foreach (new DirectoryIterator('team_b/') as $fileInfo) {
if($fileInfo->isDot() || !$fileInfo->isFile()) continue;
$team_b[] = $fileInfo->getFilename();
}

foreach (new DirectoryIterator('team_c') as $fileInfo) {
if($fileInfo->isDot() || !$fileInfo->isFile()) continue;
$team_c[] = $fileInfo->getFilename();
}

?>
<script type="text/javascript">

var variableslide = <?php echo json_encode($team_a, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)
?>
```

When I "inspect element" in Chrome whilst running the full code, I can see that the file names are being passed to Javascript, but, missing the 0,1,2,3,4 etc. I only end up with the file path.  Here's the result:

```
var variableslide =     ["team_a/blank.jpg","team_a/ford.jpg","team_a/futuristic.jpg","team_a/lambo.jpg"];
```

What I've been Googling around is how to get var variableslide array to read as such:

```
variableslide[0]=['team_a/blank.jpg']
variableslide[1]=['team_a/ford.jpg']
```

To pull the array index number and the filename from PHP and populate the variableslide array in JS so it reads the same as above.  When I print_r from the PHP script, it shows the index number and text correctly.  Can anybody please help me figure this one out!  Thanks!

Comment: Those are equivalent arrays (save for that you're wrapping your arrays in more arrays, why?). The `['..', '..', ..]` notation is just the compact literal notation.

Comment: just do it the normal way, variableslide[0]
or in the chrome console you can type variableslide[0];
it should return the team_a/blank.jpg or the first element of the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if you wont it to look like this

```
variableslide[0]=['team_a/blank.jpg']
variableslide[1]=['team_a/ford.jpg']
```

> in the php file use

```
<script type="text/javascript">

<?php
foreach($team_a as $i=>$v){ echo 'variableslide['.$i.']="'.$v.'";'."\n";}
?>
```

> insetad of

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var variableslide = <?php echo json_encode($team_a, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)
?>
```

*** ***Just notice that is the exact same thing !***

Comment: Hi Federico, thanks for the response, I tried your suggestion but then realised that you can't actually run php code within javascript, it just prints the line as text ...

Comment: // $arraycount=count($team_a); 
// $counter="0"; 
// echo " var variableslide=new Array(".$arraycount.");"; 
// while ($counter < $arraycount) { echo " variableslide[".$counter."]= ['".$team_a[$counter]."']\n"; 
    $counter++;

Comment: But, again, the echo just prints out the resulting javascript code on the page without making it actual javascript code ... Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry I think I made an error the PHP bracket is "<?php" and not "<php?". I corrected it try it again....

Comment: No problems and thanks, it's working now, I also forgot that you CAN run PHP in JS and that I should always empty my Chrome cache before running any new changes ... So sir, you are indeed correct with your code :)